# Classfication accuracy on Weka

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka

I am using `Weka` GUI for a classification. I am new to Weka and getting confused with the options

- Use training Set
- Supplied test set
- Cross validation

to train my classification algorithm (for example J48), I trained with cross validation 10 folds and the accuracy is pretty good (97%). When I test my classification - the accuracy drops to about 72%. I am so confused. Any tips please? This is how I did it:

- I train my model on the training data (For example: `train.arff`)
- I right-click in the Results list on the item which model you want to save
  select Save model and save it for example as `j48tree.model`

and then

- I load the test data (for example: `test.arff` via the Supplied test set button
- Right-click in the Results list, I selected Load model and choose j48tree.model
- I selected `Re-evaluate model on current test set`

Is the way i do it wrong? Why the accuracy miserably dropping to 72% from 97%? Or is doing only the cross-validation with 10 folds is enough to train and test the classifier?

**Note**: my training and testing datasets have the same attributes and labels. The only difference is, I have more data on the testing set which I don't think will be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any issue with how you use WEKA.

You mentioned that you test set is larger than training? What is the split? The usual rule of thumb is that test set should be one 1/4 of the whole dataset, i.e. 3 times smaller than training and definitely not larger. This alone could explain the drop from 97% to 72% which is by the way not so bad for real life case.

Also it will be helpful if you build the learning curve https://weka.wikispaces.com/Learning+curves as it will explain whether you have a bias or variance issue. Judging by your values sounds like you have a high variance (i.e. too many parameters for your dataset), so adding more examples or changing your split between training and test set will likely help.

**Update**
I ran a quick analysis of the dataset at question by randomforest and my performance was similar to the one posted by author. Details and code are available on gitpage http://omdv.github.io/2016/03/10/WEKA-stackoverflow

Comment: I am using this dataset (full training dataset and full test dataset): https://web.archive.org/web/20150205070216/http://nsl.cs.unb.ca/NSL-KDD/ . and yes you are right, I have 42 features in my dataset

Comment: I actually downloaded this dataset and classified it with Random Forest from python's scikit-learn module with very good performance. One thing which is still not clear to me is why your test set is larger than training? The downloaded set has about 17:83 split. What I did after download is merged two sets and randomly selected 20% as test set. Performance was good, as I said. So my recommendation stands - you need to adjust the split between the training and test sets.

Comment: I used this opportunity and finally published something finished on my gitpage (http://torrinos.github.io/datascience/2016/03/10/WEKA-stackoverflow.html). The code is there as well as details. Good luck.

Comment: I mark your answer as `accepted answer`. You are awesome! But instead of binary (anomaly and normal) - I wanted to use the multi-class labels as in this: https://web.archive.org/web/20150406000933/http://nsl.cs.unb.ca/NSL-KDD/KDDTrain+_20Percent.txt . Is it possible to update your answers with a multi-class label?

Comment: Nothing will change with multi-class in that script, since y-vector is getting factorized by pandas, it will just have more than two factors. In fact I just took parts from my own application I am working on right now which has three classes for outcome.

Comment: Which Python editor did you use for your code by the way? I tried it with anaconda but it does seem to have a lot of compilation errors.

Comment: It's Anaconda on Windows, python 2.7. Should work out of the box. If not - try to run some example script from scikit-learn, e.g. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html. If it doesn't work there is something wrong with your installation.